# How can i change the xml file values by bat commands. 'sed' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, sed, batch-processing, xmlstarlet

Folks,

Trying to update the XML file values using 'sed'. bat command not recognized.

CODE:

```
**@echo off
SET PREFIX=ROOM107-
SET SUFFIX=\Admin
SET /P PCNAME1=Please enter your desired NUMBER:
SET PCNAME=%PREFIX%%PCNAME1%%SUFFIX%

sed -i "s#<UserId>Admin</UserId>#<UserId>%PCNAME%</UserId>#" changexml.xml

pause**
```

Any other way to update the below XML file using BAT command ?

XML:

```
<xml>
<Main_group>
     <group_1>
        <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
        <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
     </group_1>
     <group_2>
        <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
        <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
     </group_2>
 </Main_group>
 <SubGroup>
    <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
    <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
 </SubGroup>
 </xml>
```

trying to update the value of 'A' and 'B' of the node 
like below

```
<SubGroup>
    <add key="A" value="USA"/>
    <add key="B" value="Basket Ball"/>
 </SubGroup>
```

Comment: `sed` is a *nix tool, you need to install it to MSWindows to be able to use it. However, `sed` is not a tool to process XML.

Comment: @Cyrus - thanks for the links, those links supports linux os. im looking for windows platform that too with BAT command

Comment: @choroba - Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Cyrus - Many threads bit confused . can you share some code or example here. will be great helpful

Comment: Are you sure you want to [**pͬ̎ͫa̠̹̙͐̂̊͂ͫ̾̌ͅr̥̓s̬̓̾̓̑e͔͓̝̗̼̙̞͑̏̇͛̿̀ Ẋ̴̟̼̱̱̲ͬ̒ͥ̈́ͤͅM̻̯̬̘̞̼̺̄͑ͧ͋̀̀L̘͚̳̬͇͎̻͊̅̄̑͌ ͚̭̠͙ͅw̳̖̫̘̔͐̏͘i̷͔̳̠͔͚͑ͬt̶͖̪͉͍̱ͨ̌́͂̎ͪh̋ͧ̋ͦ͏̱̭͚̗ ͉̖̫͕ͪ̓͘R̶͔͍͍̖̔ͯ̐̌eͣ͌̄͌ͤ͏̼̜̙̭͈g̝̘͕̋̑E͙͈̯̩̹ͥ̅x̟͔͉͕ͫͪ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5958455)?

Comment: @Cyrus - Thanks for the spontaneous help :) . please clarify my doubts below

Comment: @iBug - thanks for your help :) information its too complex for me. just a beginner will be really helpful for me if you share some code or examples !

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell are all scripting languages you can use in Windows and they all have native capability to read and write XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml was not valid so I've edited it a little bit (saved as xml.txt):

```
<xml>
    <Main_group>
         <group_1>
            <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
            <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
         </group_1>
         <group_2>
            <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
            <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
         </group_2>
     </Main_group>
     <SubGroup>
        <add key="A" value="AMERICA"/>
        <add key="B" value="BALL"/>
     </SubGroup>
 </xml>
```

Here's a bat file that edit his values (should be in the same directory).***Without*** need of installing external programs and the xml is parsed as xml without using regex. You can change the hardcoded values:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off


    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" 

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

//------------------------
// -- hard coded values --
var originalFile="xml.txt";
var newFile="xml1.xml";

var xpath1='//SubGroup/add[@key="A"]/@value';
var xpath2='//SubGroup/add[@key="B"]/@value';

var newValue1="USA";
var newValue2="Basket Ball";

//---------------------------

var objDoc;
var objNodes;
var loaded;

try {
    objDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
    loaded=objDoc.load(originalFile);
} catch (err){
    WScript.Echo("Error while parsing the xml");
    WScript.Echo(err.message);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

if(!loaded){
    WScript.Echo("Error while parsing the xml");
    WScript.Echo("");
    WScript.Echo("Error Code:"+objDoc.parseError.errorCode);
    WScript.Echo("");
    WScript.Echo("Line:"+objDoc.parseError.line+" Posotion:"+objDoc.parseError.filepos);
    WScript.Echo("");
    WScript.Echo("Reason:"+objDoc.parseError.reason);
    WScript.Echo("");
    WScript.Echo("URL:"+objDoc.parseError.url);
    WScript.Echo("");
    WScript.Echo(objDoc.parseError.srcText);
    WScript.Quit(5);
}



var node1=objDoc.selectSingleNode(xpath1);
var node2=objDoc.selectSingleNode(xpath2);
node1.text=newValue1;
node2.text=newValue2;


objDoc.save(newFile);
```

Comment: im not able to execute sucessfully getting error Reason:Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document

Comment: @Riv - you can change the last line with `objDoc.save(originalFile);`

Comment: @Riv - for the first comments - it seems that your xml is not valid , you have two or more root elements. You can try for example to add one more root elements that hold everything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use xmlstarlet to handle XML documents.

Here is the link to install it:
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php

After getting it working, here is the code to handle the required changes:

```
xmlstarlet ed [--inplace] -u '/xml/SubGroup/add[@key="A"]/@value' -v "USA" -u '/xml/SubGroup/add[@key="B"]/@value' -v "Basket Ball" changexml.xml
```

The argument --inplace will change the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sed` on Windows, you have to get a Unix environment like [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) or [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

However, it's not a good idea to **[parse XML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5958455)**.

Comment: Thanks for the info